# How does browser find server's MAC address

Tags: networking, routes, dns, arp

Here's the process that I understood

1. When URL is entered, browser parses the URL
2. Queries domain to DNS server to find IP addr(External IP)
3. Goes through router's routing table to find destination IP addr
4. When arrived at the router with the same external IP, broadcasts using ARP to find the exact machine and convert to MAC addr
5. Opens TCP socket and communicate

I suppose DNS server returns external IP(IP of the router) which is shared by all machines connected to that router.
My question is, in step 4, does it broadcast target machine's internal IP? If it does, where does it get target machine's internal IP?

Comment: The browser knows nothing of the remote server's MAC address. ARP is at Layer 2 and in some networks, ARP is not used at all, neither are MAC addresses. The TCP/IP stack where the browser is running will resolve the MAC address of the router using ARP (who has IP address x.x.x.x) and then forward the packet to the router. That process repeats for each step until the remote server receives the packet. To answer your last two questions: no and nowhere.

Comment: @JohnHanley if there are many servers behind 1 router, how does my packet find its way to the correct one?

Comment: NAT Routers create a table of IP port numbers. When a packet arrives for port X, it looks up the address of the system to forward the packet to. In Ethernet-based networks, IP uses ARP at Layer 2 to route packets within the LAN. If you are trying to learn networking, don't ask questions here. Go to YouTube and watch videos on networking plus study a book in depth. A good networking book with be 500+ pages. There you will find much better thought-out details.